# set size and colour of \ref{} output within \text{} environment.

Tags: cross-referencing

I am referencing a previous question within an `\overbrace{}` using `\ref{}` and would like to be able to control the output (specifically: set the colour and the font-size), but cannot figure out the correct way to do this.

For this particular case, it would be sufficient if the colour could be set globally (but not the font-size, as should be clear from context of MWE).

```
\documentclass[9pt,leqno]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=cyan]{hyper ref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\large{e.g. \arabic*.}},start=1]
% --------------------------------------- Start of Question:
% 
\item \label{Q-sqrt-exponential}%
         Question to be referenced.\\[10pt]%
% 
% ======================================= End of Qustion



Later development within which question is referenced: 
  %
    \[
        \overbrace{ \sqrt{e^x} }^{ \text{\tiny{ \ref{Q-sqrt-exponential}  }} }
    \]
  %  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

**How can I set the reference font-colour to black and the size to something relatively small?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put font commands in the label definition because they will be used in the references too, use font instead:

```
\documentclass[9pt,leqno]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=cyan]{hyper ref}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=e.g. \arabic*.,font=\bfseries\large,start=1]
% --------------------------------------- Start of Question:
%
\item \label{Q-sqrt-exponential}%
         Question to be referenced.\\[10pt]%
%
% ======================================= End of Qustion



Later development within which question is referenced:
  %
    \[
        \overbrace{ \sqrt{e^x} }^{\text{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\tiny \ref{Q-sqrt-exponential}}}
    \]
  %
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, why is this important? For convenience, I've defined a few different font commands and it is much faster for me to be able to use these in label (this is not one, obviously - I simplified my formatting substantially for the MWE).

Comment: because as you complained the fonts are used in the references too.

Comment: thank you - I didn't realize / expect that the `enum` label formatting would be passed to `ref` - extremely helpful to know. Beyond this issue then, it would be fine to continue formatting with font commands (i.e. when I won't be calling on them with ref)?

Comment: with your permission, I'd like to edit your answer to include the above clarification as it was not obvious and is directly pertinent.

Comment: The label should contain the part you want to pass to \ref.  Don't misuse it out of lazyness.